# Error when "Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate" applied

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, pnp-powershell

tried to copy template to new site on SPO. I get an error and don't know what it is about. Any idea?

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The object id "site:074957fd-1ceb-4557-a789-5e4421264993:web:0849eaa2-ca71-4863-89a7-91ee21225e95" is invalid.
```

[image]

Comment: We also run into this issue occasionally, but recently more often. Any further insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a known issue occurring occasionally. See the reporting post here: [Getting "The object id site:GUID:web:GUID" when provisioning site collection with PnP Tenant Templates #2025.](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/2025)

Maybe try a few times later and see if it works.